# Scanner class help

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to scan string that made up of three words, each word separated by a space.

e.g.

String abc = I like sport

The problem is I can only manage to return 2 words separated by a space...something like this

I like

I want to ask politely if there is a way to scan all three words and return them, without any loops or conditions.

Here is a piece of my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class fast
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        String message1;
        String message2;
        //
        String message3;
        String message4;
        //
        String message5;
        String message6;

        System.out.print("Enter message");

        message1 = scan.next(); 
        message3 = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do dont need the scanner class for that, so just to separate the words you can use `yourstring.split(" ");` to get an Array with all words.

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "1 like sport";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(" ");
```